# Return a string value from a DynamoDB table in an async C# method

Tags: c#, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

Because I'm very new to C# understanding other questions and answers related to this is very hard, so I hope this is not an exact duplicate of other questions asked here which I couldn't use to my advantage.

I have a table in DynamoDB with two columns: `reference` and `Value`. I'm trying to get the value of the `Value` column using `reference` as the partition key. This is what I've tried so far:

```
public async void GetData(string reference)
{
    var data = await _client.GetItemAsync(
        "my-data",
        new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            {"reference", new AttributeValue {S = reference}}
        }
    );

    var item = data.Item.Values.First().S;

    System.Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

I want to return the `item` variable which is a string, but because the method is `async` I am not allowed to do so. How can I return the string from this method?

Comment: `async void` is *only* meant for event handlers or similar methods. In any other case you should return a `Task<TResult>` if you want to return a result or `Task` if there's no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the method is async, you should return a `Task`. Also, avoid returning `void` from an async method usually. Instead, if there's no return value you return `Task`. There's a full explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types).

Say the type of your `item` is `T`, then in general you return from an `async` method like:

```
public async Task<T> GetData(string reference)
{
    var data = await _client.GetItemAsync(
        "my-data",
        new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            {"reference", new AttributeValue {S = reference}}
        }
    );

    return data.Item.Values.First().S;
}
```

So if your `item` is a string, it should be

```
public async Task<string> GetData(string reference)
{
    var data = await _client.GetItemAsync(
        "my-data",
        new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            {"reference", new AttributeValue {S = reference}}
        }
    );

    return data.Item.Values.First().S;
}
```